# Deduplication and filtering of Add/Remove Programs list (VBScript)

Tags: windows, windows-7, vbscript, deduplication

This script works and tells and me what is installed in Program files.

Two problems

Duplicate lines

i.e

AVG 2011 Ver: 10.0.1204

AVG 2011 Ver: 10.0.1204  Installed: 27/01/2011

and

I don't want to include lines that have key words "Update","Hotfix","Java" can any VB gurus out there help with what extra is needed in this script?

```
Option Explicit

Dim sTitle
sTitle = "Installed Programs on your PC -"
Dim StrComputer

strComputer = Trim(strComputer)
If strComputer = "" Then strComputer = "."

'Wscript.Echo GetAddRemove(strComputer)

Dim sCompName : sCompName = GetProbedID(StrComputer)

Dim sFileName
sFileName = sCompName & "_" & GetDTFileName() & "_Software.txt"

Dim s : s = GetAddRemove(strComputer)

If WriteFile(s, sFileName) Then
  'optional prompt for display
  If MsgBox("Finished processing.  Results saved to " & sFileName & _
            vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Do you want to view the results now?", _
            4 + 32, sTitle) = 6 Then
    WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run sFileName, 9
  End If
End If

Function GetAddRemove(sComp)
  'Function credit to Torgeir Bakken
  Dim cnt, oReg, sBaseKey, iRC, aSubKeys
  Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
  Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
              sComp & "/root/default:StdRegProv")
  sBaseKey = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
  iRC = oReg.EnumKey(HKLM, sBaseKey, aSubKeys)

  Dim sKey, sValue, sTmp, sVersion, sDateValue, sYr, sMth, sDay

  For Each sKey In aSubKeys
    iRC = oReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, sBaseKey & sKey, "DisplayName", sValue)
    If iRC <> 0 Then
      oReg.GetStringValue HKLM, sBaseKey & sKey, "QuietDisplayName", sValue
    End If
    If sValue <> "" Then
      iRC = oReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, sBaseKey & sKey, _
                                "DisplayVersion", sVersion)
      If sVersion <> "" Then
        sValue = sValue & vbTab & "Ver: " & sVersion
      Else
        sValue = sValue & vbTab 
      End If
      iRC = oReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, sBaseKey & sKey, _
                                "InstallDate", sDateValue)
      If sDateValue <> "" Then
        sYr =  Left(sDateValue, 4)
        sMth = Mid(sDateValue, 5, 2)
        sDay = Right(sDateValue, 2)
        'some Registry entries have improper date format
        On Error Resume Next 
        sDateValue = DateSerial(sYr, sMth, sDay)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sdateValue <> "" Then
          sValue = sValue & vbTab & "Installed: " & sDateValue
        End If
      End If
      sTmp = sTmp & sValue & vbcrlf
    cnt = cnt + 1
    End If
  Next
  sTmp = BubbleSort(sTmp)
  GetAddRemove = "INSTALLED SOFTWARE (" & cnt & ") - " & sCompName & _
                 " - " & Now() & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & sTmp 
End Function

Function BubbleSort(sTmp)
  'cheapo bubble sort
  Dim aTmp, i, j, temp
  aTmp = Split(sTmp, vbcrlf)  
  For i = UBound(aTmp) - 1 To 0 Step -1
    For j = 0 to i - 1
      If LCase(aTmp(j)) > LCase(aTmp(j+1)) Then
        temp = aTmp(j + 1)
        aTmp(j + 1) = aTmp(j)
        aTmp(j) = temp
      End if
    Next
  Next
  BubbleSort = Join(aTmp, vbcrlf)
End Function

Function GetProbedID(sComp)
  Dim objWMIService, colItems, objItem
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & sComp & "\root\cimv2")
  Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select SystemName from " & _
                                         "Win32_NetworkAdapter",,48)
  For Each objItem in colItems
    GetProbedID = objItem.SystemName
  Next
End Function

Function GetDTFileName()
  dim sNow, sMth, sDay, sYr, sHr, sMin, sSec
  sNow = Now
  sMth = Right("0" & Month(sNow), 2)
  sDay = Right("0" & Day(sNow), 2)
  sYr = Right("00" & Year(sNow), 4)
  sHr = Right("0" & Hour(sNow), 2)
  sMin = Right("0" & Minute(sNow), 2)
  sSec = Right("0" & Second(sNow), 2)
  GetDTFileName = sMth & sDay & sYr & "_" & sHr & sMin & sSec
End Function

Function WriteFile(sData, sFileName)
  Dim fso, OutFile, bWrite
  bWrite = True
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  On Error Resume Next
  Set OutFile = fso.OpenTextFile(sFileName, 2, True)
  'Possibly need a prompt to close the file and one recursion attempt.
  If Err = 70 Then
    Wscript.Echo "Could not write to file " & sFileName & ", results " & _
                 "not saved." & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "This is probably " & _
                 "because the file is already open."
    bWrite = False
  ElseIf Err Then
    WScript.Echo err & vbcrlf & err.description
    bWrite = False
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
  If bWrite Then
    OutFile.WriteLine(sData)
    OutFile.Close
  End If
  Set fso = Nothing
  Set OutFile = Nothing
  WriteFile = bWrite
End Function
```

Comment: Curious about the downvote. +1 for balance, as I've seen much poorer questions.

Comment: I could help, but since I'm not a JEDI master I'll have to decline.

Comment: David you have been knighted, your are now a Jedi Master ...

Comment: @ice As a newly knighted JEDI master I have realised that VB Script is not worthy......  ;-)

Comment: Luckily Sith Lords are able to alter the title.  Pray that I do not alter it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@icecurtain: The second part of your question can be solved using `InStr` as suggested by @Oliver, rewritten to suit your script it would look like --

```
If sValue <> "" _
    AND (InStr(1, sValue, "Hotfix", 1)) = 0 _
    AND (InStr(1, sValue, "Update", 1)) = 0 _
    AND (InStr(1, sValue, "Java", 1)) = 0) Then
```

The first part wouldn't be that tricky either except for the fact that you include a version and installation date if found (which some of the duplicates will only include in part or not at all). If the extra bits of data wasn't included, you could loop through all the lines and add them into a `Scripting.Dictory` object with a `.Exists` check to prevent a duplicate from being added.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, even if i'm not a jedi master (or have no self-respect ;-)), this could help you:

```
If InStr(1, sValue, "hotfix", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    Print "This is NOT a hotfix"
End If
```

For further informations just take a look at the [MSDN page for `InStr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think hardcoded string checks are the way to go, a uninstall entry is a update if any of these are true:

- It has a dword value named SystemComponent that is <> 0
- A string value named ParentKeyName
- The registry sub key starts with "KB" or "Q" + 6 numbers (KB######,Q######)